# Automatic pupil detection with OpenCV & node.js

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing

I'm embarking on a project that involves creating a online tool to measure the pupillary distance of a person via a webcam/camera still photo. The tricky part has to do with automatic detection of the pupils in the photo. I have little/no experience with image processing of this kind, but I've been doing some research.

So far I'm considering using openCV through node.js using this available library: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv.

Am I at all on the right track? The capabilities of this library seem limited compared to more developed ones for C++/java/python/etc, but the timeline for this project doesn't allow for my learning a new language in the process.

Just wanted to reach out to anyone with more experience with this kind of thing, and any tips/etc are more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: How is the project going? I'm looking at doing the same thing and would be interested in hearing from your experience

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about pupil detection, but eye detection is not hard, see this sample [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
opencv = require "opencv"

detect = (im) ->
    im.detectObject "./node_modules/opencv/data/haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_small.xml", {}, (err, eyepairs) ->
        im.rectangle [eyepair.x, eyepair.y], [eyepair.x+eyepair.width, eyepair.y+eyepair.height] for eyepair in eyepairs
        for eyepair in eyepairs
            if ((eyepair.x - lasteyepair.x) ** 2 + (eyepair.y - lasteyepair.y) ** 2 < 500)
                lasteyepair = eyepair
                foundEye = true
                im2 = im.roi Math.max(eyepair.x-10,0), Math.max(eyepair.y-10,0), Math.min(eyepair.width+20,im.width()), Math.min(eyepair.height+20,im.height())
                im2.detectObject "./node_modules/opencv/data/haarcascade_eye.xml", {}, (err, eyes) ->
                    im.rectangle [Math.max(eyepair.x-10+eye.x,0), Math.max(eyepair.y-10+eye.y,0)], [eyepair.x-10+eye.x+eye.width, eyepair.y-10+eye.y+eye.height] for eye in eyes
                    console.log "eyes", eyes
                    im.save "site/webcam.png"

camera = new opencv.VideoCapture 0
capture = () ->
    camera.read (err, im) ->
        if err
            camera.close()
            console.error err
        else
            detect im
            setTimeout capture, 1000

setTimeout capture, 2000
```

Detection of objects work with the [Viola-Jones method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework), which is being called asynchronously by `detectObject`. Once the detection is finished, a callback is called that can process the positions and sizes of the found objects.
I do the detection in two stages: First I detect eyepairs which is reasonably fast and stable, then I crop the image to a rectangle around the eyepair and detect eyes inside of that. If you want to detect pupils, you should then find a cascade for pupil detection (shouldn't be too hard since a pupil is basically a black dot), crop the image around each eye and detect the pupil in there.

Addendum:
My code has a little bug: `im.save` is being called multiple times for every eyepair, whereas it should only be called in the very last callback.